# Eclipse - Android "can't find tools"

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed Eclipse Indigo and the Android SDK

When I attempted to Help>Install New Software, I tried to put the Android files into C:\Users, rather than just one user.  While the installation proceeded, when I restarted to install the ADT, I got a message that eclipse 'can't find tools'.

I deleted the entire elipse folder and reinstalled from scratch.  I got the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Completly delete eclipse and sdk where you installed them.
[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtsyrKdPZVw&feature=related) will get you started.
Just put sdk and eclipse on your root c drive and youre fine.